# Axios returns a nested array with single objects after using Promise.all

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, fetch

I am using axios and my goal is to execute a get request inside a map function. The following function accept an array of Id's. The first step was to create a simple get function that will be called inside the MAP function.

In the try catch block, I set the `Promise.all()` method.

```
// Get imaged exercices
export const getImagedExercices = async array => {

    let getIds = async element => {
        let array = await axios.get(`http://localhost:3000/api/get-exercice-by-id/${element}`);
        let data = await array.data;
        return data;
    }

    try {
        const arrayEx = array.map(item => item.exerciceId);
        let mappedResult = await Promise.all(arrayEx.map(async element => await getIds(element)));
        return mappedResult;
    } 
    catch (error) { 
      console.log(error);
      return error;
    }
  }
```

The problem is that I get an array that for each existing item is wrapped inside another array that contains the actual object...

```
[
  [
    {
      id: 'clcj22d650002sbdkmmobh33l',
      bodyPart: 'waist',
      equipment: 'body weight',
      gifUrl: 'http://d205bpvrqc9yn1.cloudfront.net/0001.gif',
      name: '3/4 sit-up',
      target: 'abs'
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      id: 'clcj22d650002sbdkmmobh33l',
      bodyPart: 'waist',
      equipment: 'body weight',
      gifUrl: 'http://d205bpvrqc9yn1.cloudfront.net/0001.gif',
      name: '3/4 sit-up',
      target: 'abs'
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      id: 'clcj22d650007sbdk9ncyidv1',
      bodyPart: 'upper legs',
      equipment: 'body weight',
      gifUrl: 'http://d205bpvrqc9yn1.cloudfront.net/1512.gif',
      name: 'all fours squad stretch',
      target: 'quads'
    }
  ]
]
```

This is the response of the entire function...

Comment: What does `/api/get-exercice-by-id/${element}` return? Is it an array?

Comment: yes. It returns always an array of objects.

Comment: It would also be better to call `.map` once since it loops every time. Just loop over `array`- `array.map(item -> getIds(item.excerciseId))`

Comment: You are getting nested arrays because each of the results is an array.

Comment: `return mappedResult.flat()`

Comment: `array.map(item -> getIds(item.excerciseId))` I dont understand this. If i take it out of the promise, It won't work